On the definition of Gelfand triple
Gelfand triple is a useful concept in functional analysis and stochastic PDEs.
In chapter 4 of [Rockner and Liu, 2015], it states that:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $V$ be a reflexive Banach space such that $V\subseteq H$ continuously and densely. Then it follows that $H^*\subseteq V^*$ continuously and densely.

My question: How can I understand that $H^*\subseteq V^*$?
My thought: We may assume that $V$ is also a Hilbert space. Then, by Riesz's theorem, we know that $V^*=V$. But since $V\subseteq H$, don't we have $V^*\subseteq H^*$?

You can’t assume $V$ is a Hilbert space in general, because $V$ is dense in $H$ but may not be the entire $H$, so the restriction of the norm on $H$ to $V$ wouldn’t make it a Hilbert space. The inclusion of dual spaces is instead just the restriction map. That is, for any $\varphi \in H^\ast$, just restrict it to $V$ (or equivalently compose it with the inclusion map $V \rightarrow H$) and you obtain an element of $V^\ast$. Density of $V$ in $H$ ensures the map is injective.

@DavidGao Thanks a lot for your explanation! It is much clearer for me. But I think that I can assume that V is a Hilbert space which does not inherit the structer of H, that is ||x||_V is not necessary to equal ||x||_H when x is in V. For example V=W^{2,2} and H=L^2.

That’s true, but that requires an additional assumption that may not be satisfied, say, $L^3([0, 1])$ in $L^2([0, 1])$. (And $L^3([0, 1])$ is not even isomorphic to a Hilbert space, i.e., there is no norm on $L^3([0, 1])$ equivalent to the usual $3$-norm that makes it a Hilbert space. And it’s also reflexive, satisfying the requirements.)

The statement holds without reflexivity assumption. Morevoer it is possible that $V$ is not separable.

@RyszardSzwarc Yeah, of course, you also don’t need $H$ to be a Hilbert space. I assume the reflexivity is for the sake of other applications, not specifically for this statement.

That's true, I wanted to emphasize that $H$ may be separable, while $V$ is not.
